# Add AJAX Request for Captcha

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have this javascript file that will validate the inputs on the client side and print errors from validation that is done on the server side.

The form works but doesn't have Google ReCaptcha v2, I want to add it using AJAX but I am not sure if how can I send the validation request to the php script.

How can I do this?

```
$(window).load(function() {
    $("#loader").fadeOut("slow");
    $('#main').fadeIn("slow");
});
$(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery.validator.setDefaults({
        errorPlacement : function(error, element) {
            element.removeClass('has-success').addClass('has-error');
        }
    });
    $('#emailForm').validate( {
        submitHandler : function(form) {
            return false;
        },
        rules : {
            userEmail:{
                required: true,
                email: true
            },
            userName:{
                required : true,
                minlength : 3,
                maxlength : 50
            },
            subject: {
                required : true,
                minlength : 10
            },
            message: {
                required : true,
                minlength : 50
            }
        },
        messages : {
            userEmail:{
                required : "Please enter your Email"
            },
            userName:{
                required : "Please enter your name"
            },
            subject: {
                required : "Please enter your contact purpose",
                minlength : "Minimum length of subject must be 10 chars long."
            },
            message: {
                required : "Please enter your sweet message",
                minlength : "Minimum length of your message must be 50 chars long."
            }
        },
        errorPlacement : function(error, element) {
            $(element).closest('div.form-group').find('.help-block').html(error.html());
        },
        highlight : function(element) {
            $(element).closest('div.form-group').removeClass('has-success').addClass('has-error');
        },
        unhighlight: function(element, errorClass, validClass) {
             $(element).closest('div.form-group').removeClass('has-error').addClass('has-success');
             $(element).closest('div.form-group').find('.help-block').html('');
        }
    });

    $(document).on('click', '#sendMailBtn', function(e){



        e.preventDefault();
        if( $('#emailForm').valid() ) {
            var sendMailBtn = $('#sendMailBtn');
            sendMailBtn.button('loading');
            $.ajax({
                url: 'ajax.php',
                method: 'post',
                dataType: 'json',
                data : { data: JSON.stringify($('#emailForm').serializeObject()) },
                success: function( response ){
                    sendMailBtn.button('reset');
                    $('input,textarea').val('');
                    showSuccessMessage();
                },
                error: function( response ) {
                    sendMailBtn.button('reset');
                    if( response.status === 400 || response.status === 403 || response.status === 500 ) {
                        showWarningMessage(response.responseJSON.message);
                    } else {
                        showWarningMessage();
                    }
                }
            });
        }

        return false;
    });

    function showSuccessMessage(){
        swal({
            title: "Many Thanks!!!",
            text: "Thanks for contacting us, We will get back to your inbox shortly...",
            type: "success",
            html: true
            /*imageUrl: "img/thumbs-up.jpg"*/
        });
    }

    function showWarningMessage(message){
        if(typeof message === 'undefined' || message === '' ) message = "Something went wrong, Please try again.";
        swal({
            title: "Oops...",
            text: message,
            type: "error",
            html: true
        });
    }

    $.fn.serializeObject = function()
    {
        var o = {};
        var a = this.serializeArray();
        $.each(a, function() {
            if (o[this.name] !== undefined) {
                if (!o[this.name].push) {
                    o[this.name] = [o[this.name]];
                }
                o[this.name].push(this.value || '');
            } else {
                o[this.name] = this.value || '';
            }
        });
        return o;
    };
});
```